# Python list in a QML ComboBox

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

QML Newbie.
Trying to set a python list as a QML ComboBox.
I created a small usage example. Note that in the real program, the python list is not hardcoded.

Python Class:

```
class Test(QObject):
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()

    @Slot(result=list)
    def getList(self):
        return ["one", "two", "three"]
```

main.py:

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    test = Test()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("Test", test)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'main.qml')))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        raise Exception("No qml objects were loaded!")
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

QML component:

```
ComboBox {
        id: combo
        width: parent.width
        model: Test.getList() // no idea what to write here
        textRole: "fileName"

        onAccepted: {
            print(combo.currentText)
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: change to `@Slot(result="QVariantList")` and remove `textRole: "fileName"`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the answer, I'm having import issues with QVariantType from PySide2. what exactly do I need to import in order to use this class?